# Preferred Automation for an application in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Which is the preferred language(within selenium) if you are testing an application developed in python

Comment: A correct (but useless) answer to this question is "Yes". Please review the information in the Help Center, especially https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask then edit this question to explain what research you have done and why you feel the need to use Selenium with Java rather than Selenium with Python.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can. Whatever language you use for your application development, if your application exposes web interface to the user, Selenium web driver will be able to interact with it (including Java-language wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you can use selenium with Java however I would strongly suggest to use python with Selenium for 2 reasons:

1) First python is far less verbose and easy to write and understand compared to Java.

2)As developers are also using python then it's better to stay in same language as well .That way even developers can contribute/support you in issues and can share the tools/ libraries/frameworks , basically the whole ecosystem of python.

I would strongly suggest to look into robot framework.

Comment: while some prefer to test using the same language as the app itself it is more opinion based then a must.
I find Python simplicity faster and more convenient for testing, a lot of tasks can be accomplished in than less than half of the time using Python compared to Java.
Sharing libraries has it's pluses but also some draw backs, for example you test yourself against the same software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can (test Python app with Java), but I don't see a reason why anyone would want to. I am saying it as a developer who used both Java and Python (IOW I am not arguing from ignorance).

- The only reason why someone might prefer Java over Python (slightly faster code) does not apply for test automation (because browser automation is inherently slow, gaining nothing)
- OTOH, developing in Python is substantially faster, because you don't have to argue with type police, and text parsing, data structures and file manipulation is more flexible in Python
- If your developers have sharp Python skills, why dilute skills by becoming also mediocre java programmers?
- If you don't know Python (yet), this is perfect opportunity to learn it - just ask Python developers for help. If you know java, you can learn Python over a single weekend, and you will be glad you did.